# how to get openlitespeed webadmin password or reset litespeed admin panel password?

Tags: php, passwords, litespeed, web-admin

I installed openlitespeed by following step:

1. `wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/litespeedtech/ols1clk/master/ols1clk.sh`
2. `bash ols1clk.sh -w`

After this, I tried  to login to `http://myip:7080/login.php`. And I tried `admin` and `123456` but failed.

can't remember if I set the password. Anyone knows how to reset it?

Comment: `$ cat /usr/local/lsws/adminpasswd`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following to reset:
 /usr/local/lsws/admin/misc/admpass.sh